# Desabilitar teclado em alguns campos

Tags: jquery

Preciso fazer a letra f só funcionar em campos de texto, em outros lugares ela não funciona, exemplo:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
               return false;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para isso basta que, nos campos de texto, você impeça a **propagação** do evento - de modo que o código genérico não atue nele. Além disso, é melhor tratar do `keydown` em vez do `keyup` pois - no momento que o `keyup` é ativado - o efeito de pressionar a tecla já aconteceu.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 70) { 
        return false; // Equivalente a: e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$('input[type="text"]').keydown(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/6DX7T/). No `textarea` a tecla <kbd>F</kbd> não terá nenhum efeito (pois está sendo tratada pelo *handler* global), mas na caixa de texto ela funciona normalmente.