# Teclado alternativo no input text

Tags: jquery

Como fazer uma tecla funcionar só em campos do tipo text quando pressionada ?

Exemplo:

```
$(":text").keydown(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

aqui falta a textarea:

```
if (e.keyCode == 70 && $(e.target).attr('type') != 'text' && $(e.target).attr('type') != 'password') {
}
```

Comment: Qual tecla você quer que funcione apenas em campos do tipo text??

Comment: tecla e e d!!!!

Comment: Não entendi. Em que casos você quer que essas teclas não façam nada?

Comment: Se explicar qual a funcionalidade que pretende fica mais fácil responder acertado. A pergunta não está 100% clara...

Comment: Qual a diferença entre essa pergunta e a [outra que você fez há uns dias](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13472/215)? Sua dúvida é em como selecionar os campos textuais, ou em como tratar dos eventos de tecla pressionada?

Answer (score 2):

Para impedir que a tecla seja registada se:

- a tecla for diferente de `d` ou `e`
- o campo não tiver `type=text`

Pode usar assim:

```
$('input, textarea').keydown(function (e) { 
    e.stopPropagation();
    var teclasAceites = e.which == 68 || e.which == 69 || false;
    if (!teclasAceites || $(e.target).attr('type') != 'text') return false;
});
```

### [Exmplo online](http://jsfiddle.net/fZh9j/1)

Coloquei `textarea` também, mas se o seu HTML não tiver, pode tirar

Comment: Ok, mas isso irá falhar se algo impedir a propagação do evento em um ou mais campos específicos. http://jsfiddle.net/2Vh4g/.

Comment: @bfavaretto, verdade. Então talvez seja melhor assim: http://jsfiddle.net/2Vh4g/1/

Comment: Estou confuso, na verdade não entendi a pergunta!

Answer (score 1):

Faça isso:

```
$(function(){

    // vincule o evento o keydown em todos os input type text
    $(":text").keydown(function(e) {
        // se o evento entra aqui ele não se propaga. não sendo cancelado na função global
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    var cancelKeypress = false;

    // função global que captora todos os demais keydown na pagina e cancela os que você desejar;
    document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        // na expressão regular você indica os keycodes que você quer bloquear, no caso 68 = d e 69 = f
        cancelKeypress = /^(68|69)$/.test("" + evt.keyCode);
        if (cancelKeypress) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    // hack para o opera
    /* For Opera */
    document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
        if (cancelKeypress) {
            return false;
        }
    };
});
```

Um exemplo [**aqui**](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/6fRnb/1/)

E `textarea` é uma tag html e não um `type` do `input`:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

> Obs: é importante a ordem da delegate dos eventos, pois o do campo text tem que ocorrer antes do evento global.